# How to send a Message object type via CXF Jax-ws

Tags: java, cxf, cxf-client

i want to send an org.apache.cxf.message.Message object via CXF Jax-ws. For example:

1. A service declared:

   ```
   @WebService
   public interface HelloWorld {
       void send(Message msg);
   }
   ```
2. Implementation of this service:

   ```
   public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
       public void send(Message msg) {
           System.out.println("receives msg id:" +((MessageImpl)msg).getId());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Server:

   ```
   HelloWorldImpl implementor = new HelloWorldImpl();
   JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory1 = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
   svrFactory1.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
   svrFactory1.setAddress("http://192.168.56.1:9000/HelloWorld");
   svrFactory1.setServiceBean(implementor);
   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server server1 = svrFactory1.create();
   server1.start();
   ```
4. Client:

   ```
   JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
   factory.setAddress("http://192.168.56.1:9000/HelloWorld");
   HelloWorld client = factory.create(HelloWorld.class);
   Message msg = new MessageImpl();
   msg.setId("abc");
   client.send(msg);
   ```

I receive an error when running as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault occurred while processing.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.sayHiToUser(Unknown Source)
at objecttype.Client.main(Client.java:60)


Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Fault occurred while processing.
.......
```

How to correct this error ?

Regards,

Comment: can you post your pojo class that you want to send

Comment: the class that i want to send in CXF: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageImpl.